# Finding a list of elements that end with a string by using Selenium with Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium

I have a method that checks whether a panel is displayed or not.

```
   def verifyNav(section)
    wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
    wait.until { @driver.find_element(:id => section + '-panel').displayed? == true }
  end
```

Now I want to add some code that says that any other elements that have an id that ends in '-panel' should not be displayed.

I've done some searching and I found that I can use the end_with method and there seems to be a find_elements method that returns a list of matching elements.

I've found out that

```
a = 'radio-panel'
a.end_with?('-panel')
```

returns true.. but if I try to call

```
@driver.find_elements(:id => end_with?('-panel'))
```

I get an error saying that end_with is an undefined method.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: I guess that `end_with?` method is defined nowhere. What about using a CSS selector? `@driver.find_elements(:css => '[id$="-panel"]')`

Comment: Thanks @SebastianPalma this works :)

Comment: Great, would you make an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This would help you

```
 p @driver.find_elements(xpath: "(.//*)[contains(@id, '-panel')]").select{|element|element.attribute("id").end_with?"-panel"}
```

If you want to iterate and wanted to do perform some action on each element, then you can do

```
@driver.find_elements(xpath: "(.//*)[contains(@id, '-panel')]").select{|element|element.attribute("id").end_with?"-panel"}.each do |i|
  puts i.displayed?  # Or whatever operation you want to perform
end
```

If you want to check whether all the element with id which consist of `-panel` is displayed

```
p @driver.find_elements(xpath: "(.//*)[contains(@id, '-panel')]")
    .select{|element|element.attribute("id").end_with?"-panel"}
    .map{|element| element.displayed?}
    .all?
```